# Visual Studio always "gets from server" every time I open the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I just recently mapped a project from TFS to my local. Whenever I try to open the solution, Visual Studios then "GETS" it from the server... every time!

Normally, this does not happen when opening a new solution.

Is there a reason why this might be happening? And how can I stop it?

Comment: when you say gets, do you mean check out or get latest from server? if it's check out do you have a reference to Enterprise Library?

Comment: I believe it starts to get the latest code again from the server.

Comment: do you have admin rights on TFS? under settings > source control. is get latest version on opening checked?